# How do I optimize SEO in a multiblog WordPress install?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, optimization

We are about to launch two product pages plus a corporate website. The goal is to keep a blog in all of the sites, but here it comes the question about how to do it in a way we get everything unified but do not mess with Google's web crawlers.

We considered the following options:

- Putting a blog from which we retrieve two categories with custom CSS,
  so we have a blog that sub splits two category-dependent blogs; this
  way we can get the feeds and will point to it
- Putting two product blogs of which we retrieve their posts into a bigger, corporate blog
- Putting three independent blogs

Despite I was for the first option, so we only have to address our content from the product pages, I would sincerely like to hear your opinion. We are afraid duplicate content or strange link games may make us lose PageRank. How would you do it?

Comment: Why do you want to create a site for a product page (twice) and don't put the product pages into the corporate site?

Comment: Because the products are web applications. They do also have their dedicated page in the Corporate site.

Comment: Ok and do you think you can speak about a product to the point of creating a dedicated blog?

Comment: Good point! The problem is that we are a committee and we have to decide. You made a good argument ;)

Answer (score 1):

One blog on each site can be a solution but I don't think it's the best in your case.

Four good reasons to only create a blog on the corporate site:

1. if you're obliged to have a site for each product (it's your case), you may be not things enough to speak about a product for creating a blog
2. three blogs take a lot of time to manage whereas it's easy and faster to publish all articles on one specific blog
3. if you have dedicated pages on products on the corporate site, its blog could speak about these products without being off-topic.
4. by speaking about products on the corporate site blog, you give much SEO value (PageRank) the the main site